# Problem Swapping Pairs Between 2 Arrays

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm

I'm working on a mutation algorithm for a homework project and I'm stumped at why I'm getting duplicates in the set. I'm trying to find a solution for the travelling ant problem (find shortest path for food) problem using a genetic mutation heuristic:

```
private static ArrayList<Node> mutate(ArrayList<Node> mutator) {
    ArrayList<Node> mutant = new ArrayList<Node>(mutator);

    Collections.rotate(mutant, 1);
    //Collections.shuffle(mutant, r);

    for (int i = 0; i < mutant.size() - 1; i++) {
        double mutantCoupleDistance     = mutant.get(i).getDistanceToNext(mutant.get(i+1));
        double mutatorCoupleDistance    = mutator.get(i).getDistanceToNext(mutator.get(i+1));

        if (mutantCoupleDistance < mutatorCoupleDistance) {
            // If the mutant gene has worse "fitness" then we'll take the good gene
            // from the mutator.
            Node tmp = mutant.get(i);
            mutant.set(i, mutator.get(i));
            mutator.set(i, tmp);

            tmp = mutant.get(i+1);
            mutant.set(i+1, mutator.get(i+1));
            mutator.set(i+1, tmp);
        }
    }

    return 
        mutant;
}
```

The array that I'm passing into the method is 49999 elements. It is being used like in a way like so:

```
        long
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        do {
            nodeList = mutate(nodeList);
        } while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 500);
```

I do not get any duplicates when I remove the swapping code from my mutate algorithm which is understandable. However, I'm having trouble understanding why I'm getting duplicates in the mutated list.

The node list starts off with no duplicates. The code I'm using to report duplicates is the following code:

```
    HashSet<Node> set = new HashSet<Node>(nodeList);

    if(set.size() < nodeList.size()){
        System.out.println("duplicates found Set:" + set.size() + " vs. NodeList:" + nodeList.size());
    }
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: A trick you can do to swap is `mutator.set(i, mutant.set(i, mutator.get(i)));` but I don't see how it would help.

How often are you getting duplicates? Can you get the error on a smaller set which is more manageable? Is the problem reproduceable so you can have a look at it in a debugger?

Comment: So, you rotate the copy by 1. Then at some points, you swap items from the copy and the original at the same index. Then after a swap, you have two equal elements next to each other. For example, `a b c d` and rotated copy `d a b c`, and swap at index 1, gives `a a c d` and `d b b c`. How could it _not_ make duplicates???

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Thank you for that tip :)

Comment: @Ishtar: I see. Thank you for the example, I will accept that as an answer if you post it and find another way to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't use GA's often, but the code does not look like a genetic algorithm to me. Is `NodeList mutator` a chromosome or a generation? What is the fitness function? What is the problem with duplicates? Or could you explain what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: @Ishtar: I have a list of points which represent food on a table. An ant is placed on the table then must go around and eat the food on the table using the least amount of energy (i.e. smallest distance). The overall fitness is the length of the path. The mutator list is the current working path and is hopefully shorter than the previous mutation (assuming this is the chromosome). No duplicates because the ant cannot eat a piece of food twice. I am trying to create mutations of the working path and pick out the better gene pairs (smaller distance between pairs) to put into the mutant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the code does now is rotate the copy by 1. Then at some points, you swap items from the copy and the original at the same index. Then after a swap, you have two equal elements next to each other. For example, `a b c d` and rotated copy `d a b c`:

```
abcd
 ▲
 swap here
 ▼
dabc
```

Gives

```
aacd
dbbc
```

Every swap will give a duplicate. The code rotates the array and makes duplicates.

From your comment it sounds like you're using [Hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) for something close to the [Traveling Salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_salesman_problem). But, if you want GA, you need a lot of `ArrayList<Node> mutator` or working paths, and randomly combine those into new ones.